# WinForms Chart: Set minimum Y Axis display range

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, visualization

I have a Winforms chart in which I have temperature readings arriving and displaying every second. I like the way the chart works automatically handling the display of the values, but I want to change *one simple thing*.

I want to increase the minimum displayed y axis range, so it displays a range of 20. At the moment it only displays around 5. I have tried a few things:

```
//(when new data arrives...)
//Does not work, I think because by default, Size is always NaN?
if (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Size < 20)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Size = 20;
}
```

None of these work either:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 20;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 20;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.MinSize = 20;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum //doesn't seem to have any effect
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum //doesn't seem to have any effect
```

I'm sure I've missed something simple. I hope I have anyway.

Comment: You are probably talking about ChartAreas > Axes > Y axis > Scale category, Minimum and Maximum property.

Comment: `ScaleView` is about zooming and scrolling. Use `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum` and  `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum`

Comment: @TaW I forgot to mention that one - doesn't work. Just tried again just to b sure.

Comment: Of course it works. But you may have done it wrong or have funny expectations. Show the (real) code and describe the results you got. What I see doesn't compile. Also do not set the ScaleView unless you know what you are doing. Leave as much on Auto (NaN) as possible..

Comment: Note that you need to __know__ the range you want to set! If you don't you will have to find out; best not all the time as this will lead to a jumpy behaviour..

Comment: I def got concept of `AxisY.Minimum` & `Maximum` wrong, but It's still not working for me. I'll post the code in a bit.

Comment: Also note a range is not a number but two numbers!

Comment: @TaW What do you mean? All I want is a constant value for this minimum range property I'm searching for. Do you mean I have to use these min and max values to set specific ranges? e.g Min = 15 Max = 25 ? Theres no way I can specify a _minimum range_ for the Axis?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a 'minimum range property'. A range always goes from a minimum to a maximum. You can adapt these values when your values suggest it but it is either all Auto, which will fit in all values or you set the range with a from- and a to-value. - You can always query the values for their current minimum, maximum or average, if you want to.

Comment: @TaW What I mean by 'minimum range property', I thought would be self-explanatory, but it is a `range` to display. I don't want to cap the axis values, I just want to _display_ a larger _range_ of values on the Y Axis. no defined min and max values, just an amount of Y Axis values that the display is not to zoom in more than. Ya geet Mi?

Comment: minimum _display_ range.

Comment: _I thought would be self-explanatory_ A common mistake ;-) - and then one wonders both why it doesn't exist and why nobody understands.. - If think you can __fake__ what you aim for: Add two __transparent dummy points__ instead of setting fixed Minima/Maxima. Give them those y-values, maybe `0` and `20` . Then when larger values get added the displayed range will grow and if you remove them it'l shrink again but never below the dummy range. You may want to create a dummy series for this purpose.

Comment: Haha, yeah. That's a good idea, but seems as my envisioned property is non-existent, I think I will leave it. It may not look so bad when the application is complete & fully operational. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'minimum display range' is not something built-in in the MSChart control.

But you can easily fake it:

Add a **dummy** `Series` which contains only **two** points to make sure the display range will not go below the range of their y-values..:

```
int rangeMin = -10; 
int rangeMax = 20; 

sDummy = chart.Series.Add("dummy");
sDummy.Color = Color.Transparent;
sDummy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
sDummy.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
sDummy.Points.AddXY(0, rangeMin + 1);
sDummy.Points.AddXY(0, rangeMax - 1);
```

Style your y-axis as you like:

```
Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
ay.MajorGrid.Interval = 5;
```

And add one or more **data** `Series`:

```
sData = chart.Series.Add("data");
sData.LegendText = "Temperature";
sData.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Now as you add data points with a **larger** range of values the y-axis will **grow** its display range to accommodate them.  And if you **remove** the larger points it will **shrink** back, but **not below the range** needed for the dummy series..:

[image]

Note that since the `Chart` automatically adds some **slack** I reduce the range on both sides by `1`; with other `Intervals` etc other numbers are needed..

The code to remove the larger values, btw:

```
var toRemove = sData.Points.Cast<DataPoint>()
                    .Where(x => x.YValues[0] >= rangeMax).ToList();
foreach (var dp in toRemove) sData.Points.Remove(dp);
```

Comment: Thanks TaW, that's a really good workaround; I will come back to this later on if I'm still not happy with it.